# Erratic output when printing HTML string

Tags: c++

I have tried to use `wstring` to store values with HTML tags so that the output would be in HTML format, which I can design however I'd like. The problem is that when I try to print it the output shows wild characters. What is wrong with the following?

```
   wstring body = L"<html><head><style>table{border: 1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;}";
    body += L"th,td{padding: 15px;}</style></head>";
    body += L"<table style='width:50%'><tr><th colspan='2'>header image</th>  </tr>";
    body += L"<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>";
    body += L"<tr><td colspan='2'>Dear #USERNAME#</td></tr>";
    body += L"</table></body></html>";
```

Comment: Can it be that the problem is with the conversion of `wstring` to `ASCII`? Is there any reason not to use `std::string`?

Comment: also show the output you're getting

Comment: output is just 2 chinese-like characters.

Comment: and when i try to use std::string, all output are chinese characters.

Comment: How do you *print*? `std::wcout << body << std::endl;` should be correct, as `printf("%S\n", body.c_str());`. Of course `printf("%s", body);` will only show garbage because a `std::string` or `std::wstring` is **not** a char or wchar array...

Comment: how did you solve the issue?

Comment: @Beginner i use this and it works fine. `(LPCVOID)&body[0]`